# emulator for wp7.1 shows internal error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-8

I've just started developing for windows phone 7 but can't seem to get my emulator working. I get an pop-up "`Internal Error`" and as a description in the bottom view i see "`Error!   Connection failed because of invalid command-line arguments`".

I am running windows 8 developer preview (not in a virtual machine) on a mac mini(2gb ram, core2Duo 2,26Ghz). I've reinstalled the tools and have restarted the computer several times but nothing works. I am running VS as an administrator

Comment: Does the same thing happen on production Windows 7? If not... sounds like a Windows bug.

Comment: i don't think that it is.. as i've seen from searching, the emulator is very buggy.. anyway, can't test it on windows 7 on the same machine.

Comment: @Badescu all in all did You try it at Win7?

Comment: first problem was because the OS (on Win7 works fine), second was ram(only 2gb, now 4). Problem fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Phone 7 SDK does not support Windows 8.

You can see the system requirements (including supported operating systems) at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570

Answer (score 3):

Still there is a work around. Try installing an update WPSDK-7.1.1-KB2669191-x86. 
and it all works perfectly.